# Setting column contents as variable in function (R)

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a table in R that calculates summary statistics based on a group ("Treatment") as part of a longer function. Before running the function I'm inputting the dataframe name (data) and column (y) I want summarized.

```
data = df
y = df$columna

    x <- function(model) {
    summary <- data %>% 
    group_by(Treatment) %>% 
    summarize(Mean= mean(y), StdError = se(y), Mean_StdError = mean(y) + se(y), Max= max(y), Min= min(y), 
    Range = max(y)-min(y),   n = n()) }
```

However, it seems that because y is saved as a new variable that is not associated with the dataframe, R is calculating summary statistics for the whole data set rather than grouping by treatment. How can I set up my code so that I can designate which column I want (y) as a variable outside of the function, instead of replacing y with df$columna? I want to set it up so I can easily run the function on a variety of different columns and dataframes. I'm guessing I need to reference the column differently? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass dataframe and column name in the function. Also `y` is the column value, you should instead pass column name in the function to keep it flexible. Try the following with non-standard evaluation.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

x <- function(data, y) {
   data %>% 
     group_by(Treatment) %>% 
     summarize(Mean= mean({{y}}), 
               StdError = se({{y}}), 
               Mean_StdError = mean({{y}}) + se({{y}}), 
               Max= max({{y}}), Min= min({{y}}), 
               Range = max({{y}})-min({{y}}),   
               n = n()) 
}
```

Now you can call the function as :

```
x(df, columna)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this solved it! As a follow-up, I have another function making a boxplot where this method doesn't seem to work. In that case I thought y would be the column name instead of the value? But I tried both using the non-standard evaluation method and the original way and neither seem to work.           Ex. `x <- function(data, y2){boxplot({{y2}} ~ Treatment, col=c("white","lightgray"),data)}`  doesn't work when I do `x(df, columna)`, nor does `x <- function(data, y2){boxplot(y2 ~ Treatment, col=c("white","lightgray"),data)}`

Comment: In that case, you can use `x <- function(data, y2){  var <- deparse(substitute(y2)); boxplot(reformulate('Treatment', var), col=c("white","lightgray"),data)}` and then do `x(df, columna)`